# I have 4 point and I want to find the shortest path given the starting point

Tags: python

```
x1 = 7
y1 = 5
x2 = 8
y2 = 7
x3 = 12
y3 = 9
x4 = 13
y4 = 12

import math

d1 = math.sqrt(x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2
d2 = math.sqrt(x3 - x1)**2 + (y3 - y1)**2
d3 = math.sqrt(x4 - x1)**2 + (y4 - y1)**2
d4 = math.sqrt(x3 - x2)**2 + (y3 - y2)**2
d5 = math.sqrt(x4 - x2)**2 + (y4 - y2)**2
d6 = math.sqrt(x4 - x3)**2 + (y4 - y3)**2
distances = [(d1 + d5 + d6 + d2), (d3 + d6 + d4 + d1)]

print(f"the shortest path is {min(distances)} cm and the longest path is {max(distances)} cm")
```

and by doing that I set my starting point to be `X1`, `Y1`, and I basically connect the dots. But what if I need to find the distance from `x1,y1` through `n` points, `x1 y1` is a given. What should I do to optimize the process? Thank you.

Comment: Is this somehow related to the "Traveling Salesman Problem"? Search for that term online if you don't know it yet. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Note: you need to add parentheses to the equations: `math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)`. Else you just take the square root of `x2 - x1`

Comment: Can you give example input/output? Are you given the `n` points and need to sum the distance of that path (ex: `n=3` and path is `(x1,y1)-(x3,y3)-(x2,y2)`)? Or do you need to find the shortest path?

Comment: There are only six possible paths.  Just try them all, and pick the shortest one. - so you're on the right track with your code.  In `distances`, each expression should include only three distances, as there are thee jumps to hit all four points.  Just add all six possible paths to `distances` and you should be done.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version of your code that computes the lengths of the six possible segments and then finds the min and max of each of the six possible paths that start at x1,y1 and visit all four points:

```
import math

x1 = 7
y1 = 5
x2 = 8
y2 = 7
x3 = 12
y3 = 9
x4 = 13
y4 = 12

d12 = d21 = math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)
d13 = d31 = math.sqrt((x3 - x1)**2 + (y3 - y1)**2)
d14 = d41 = math.sqrt((x4 - x1)**2 + (y4 - y1)**2)
d23 = d32 = math.sqrt((x3 - x2)**2 + (y3 - y2)**2)
d24 = d42 = math.sqrt((x4 - x2)**2 + (y4 - y2)**2)
d34 = d43 = math.sqrt((x4 - x3)**2 + (y4 - y3)**2)
distances = [(d12+d23+d34), (d12+d24+d43), (d13+d32+d24), (d13+d34+d42), (d14+d42+d23), (d14+d43+d32)]

print(f"the shortest path is {min(distances):.2f} cm and the longest path is {max(distances):.2f} cm")
```

Result:

```
the shortest path is 9.87 cm and the longest path is 20.76 cm
```

There's really no need to optimize this simple case.  One might argue that the code should be written to account for larger sets of points efficiently.  The problem with this is that to handle any challenging number of points requires not just a simple optimization or two, but rather a considerably complex algorithm.  Getting this problem "right" in an optimized way is beyond the scope of what you should expect to get here.

To get an idea of what I mean by a "considerably complex algorithm", take a look at [The Traveling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) of which your problem is a variation.  Per this article, the problem is "one of the most intensively studied problems in optimization".  You can trivially change your code to solve the classic TSP for your four points by just adding the fourth jump to each group of distances in the computation of `distances`:

```
distances = [(d12+d23+d34+d41), (d12+d24+d43+d31), (d13+d32+d24+d41), (d13+d34+d42+d21), (d14+d42+d23+d31), (d14+d43+d32+d21)]
```

UPDATE: Here's another take on the problem that does the same thing, but more concisely:

```
import math

points = ((7, 5), (8, 7), (12, 9), (13, 12))

# The six possible routes (as indexes into the "points" tuple)
# to hit each point once starting at the first point
paths = ((0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 3, 2), (0, 2, 1, 3), (0, 2, 3, 1), (0, 3, 1, 2), (0, 3, 2, 1))

def dist(p1, p2):
    return math.sqrt((p2[0]-p1[0])**2 + (p2[1]-p1[1])**2)

distances = []

# Compute a list of the total distances traveled for each path in "paths"
for path in paths:
    distances.append(dist(points[path[0]], points[path[1]]) +
                     dist(points[path[1]], points[path[2]]) +
                     dist(points[path[2]], points[path[3]]))

print(f"the shortest path is {min(distances):.2f} cm and the longest path is {max(distances):.2f} cm")
```

This solution is admittedly less efficient, as it computes the distances between points multiple times.  With so few combinations, this makes no real difference.  To fix this at the cost of a more complex piece of code, you could write a version of the `dist` function that cached prior computations so that it only computed the distance between any two points once:

```
# Optimized distance calculator that caches results so that the distance between any two
# pairs of points is only computed once.
distance_cache = {}
def dist(p1, p2):
    key = (p1, p2)
    if key not in distance_cache:
        if (p2, p1) in distance_cache:
            distance_cache[key] = distance_cache[(p2, p1)]
        else:
            distance_cache[key] = math.sqrt((p2[0] - p1[0]) ** 2 + (p2[1] - p1[1]) ** 2)
    return distance_cache[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

Optimization is use Prim algorithm with heap

**Code**

```
from heapq import heappush, heappop

def find_min_path(points):
    '''
        min path starting at points[0] using Prim's heap based algorithm
    '''
    def distance(p1, p2):
        ' Distance between two points in 2D '
        d = (p1[0] - p2[0])**2 + (p1[1] - p2[1])**2
        return d**0.5
    
    h = []                 # Empy heap
    path = [points[0]]     # Add first point to path
    heappush(h, (0, path)) # Add to heap tuple of (distance, path)

    while h:
        # Expand path with smallest total distance
        d, path = heappop(h)

        if len(path) == len(points):
            # Completed path
            break

        for p in points[1:]:   
            # for all points not in starting point
            if not p in path:
                # Extend if point p not in path
                # distance increases by distance to last point in path to p
                # path extended by p
                heappush(h, (d + distance(p, path[-1]), path + [p]))
                
    return d, path
```

**Test**

```
# List of 2D points
points = [(7, 5), (8, 7), (12, 9), (13, 12)]

d, path = find_min_path(points)
print(f'Min Distance {d:.4f} using path {*path,}')
```

**Output**

```
Min Distance 9.8705 using path ((7, 5), (8, 7), (12, 9), (13, 12))
```